# MySQL if else in SELECT not working

Tags: mysql

i was trying to perform the following query without any success.
It's the first time i'm using the if else statement in SQL, can you verify what's wrong on it?
Thanks for your precious help!

```
SELECT 
        members.id AS friendID, 
        members.username AS friendName, 
        members.mainPicture AS thumbnail, 
        COUNT(*) AS numROW 
        FROM members 
        WHERE members.id IN (
            SELECT (IF (friends.senderID = 9, friends.receiverID, 
                        IF (friends.senderID <> 9, friends.senderID)
                       )
                   ) 
            AS fid 
            FROM friends 
            WHERE (friends.senderID = 9 OR friends.receiverID = 9) AND friends.approved=1
            )
            )
```

Comment: please answer in an Answer, not a comment. I have copied your answer.

Comment: Hello Kickstart, thantk for your comment, you are right regarding the single if!
anyway i got only 1 result while i should get 3 records.
I try to explane what i'm doing:
I need to find all the records from friends where senderID or receiverID = 9, getting as output the senderID if it's not equal to 9 else get the receiverID and viceversa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully answer.

A major problem is that you have no group by. Hence if more than one member.id would be returned, they would all be rolled up into one row. Which members.id / username / mainPicture that would be returned would be undefined. This is also why you only get a single row returned.

Secondly your IF clause. The IF statement has 3 parameters. If the first is true then the 2nd is returned else the 3rd is returned. In this instance the 3rd parameter is another IF (which is fine, you can embed them). But that IF has no 3rd parameter.

As such your SQL probably should be as follows:-

```
SELECT  members.id AS friendID, 
        members.username AS friendName, 
        members.mainPicture AS thumbnail, 
        COUNT(*) AS numROW 
FROM members 
WHERE members.id IN 
(
    SELECT IF (friends.senderID = 9, friends.receiverID, friends.senderID) AS fid 
    FROM friends 
    WHERE (friends.senderID = 9 OR friends.receiverID = 9) 
    AND friends.approved = 1
)
GROUP BY members.id AS friendID, members.username AS friendName, members.mainPicture AS thumbnail
```

The down side of this is that it is using an IN clause with a sub query, which can perform oddly. Also the sub query has an OR of 2 different fields which will prevent it using indexes.

This should return one row per member (assuming member.id is unique), but the counter will always be 1.

As such it might be more efficient to do the following instead, which I suspect gets you what you want

```
SELECT  members.id AS friendID, 
        members.username AS friendName, 
        members.mainPicture AS thumbnail, 
        (f1.aCount + f2.aCount) AS numROW 
FROM members 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT receiverID, COUNT(*) AS aCount 
    FROM friends  
    WHERE senderID = 9 
    AND approved = 1
    GROUP BY receiverID
) f1
ON members.id = f1.receiverID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT senderID, COUNT(*) AS aCount 
    FROM friends  
    WHERE receiverID = 9 
    AND approved = 1
    GROUP BY senderID
) f2
ON members.id = f2.senderID
```

This gets a count of all the friend records for a member.

If the friends table has a unique id field then you could possibly use something like this which should enable it to use indexes properly:-

```
SELECT  members.id AS friendID, 
        members.username AS friendName, 
        members.mainPicture AS thumbnail, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT f1.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT f2.id) AS numROW 
FROM members 
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f1 ON members.id = f1.receiverID AND f1.senderID = 9 AND f1.approved = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f2 ON members.id = f2.senderID AND f2.receiverID = 9 AND f2.approved = 1
GROUP BY members.id AS friendID, members.username AS friendName, members.mainPicture AS thumbnail
```

If you just want the list of friends with no counts (which rereading your comment sounds possible) then the following will do it and should be fairly efficient (each separate query can use indexes, the UNION will sort out any duplicates):-

```
SELECT  members.id AS friendID, 
        members.username AS friendName, 
        members.mainPicture AS thumbnail 
FROM members 
INNER JOIN friends  
ON members.id = friends.receiverID 
WHERE senderID = 9 
AND approved = 1
UNION
SELECT  members.id AS friendID, 
        members.username AS friendName, 
        members.mainPicture AS thumbnail
FROM members 
INNER JOIN friends  
ON members.id = friends.senderID 
WHERE receiverID = 9 
AND approved = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Kickstart! the third one is absolutely what i was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Big problem appears to be you have no `GROUP BY` clause. `COUNT(*)` depends for its correct operation on `GROUP BY`.

Problem with the IF is that the 2nd one has no else condition. It probably should be a a single IF:

```
 IF(friends.senderID = 9, friends.receiverID, friends.senderID)
```